# Postgres upsert using on conflict - multiple fields in on conflict condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, upsert

I'm trying to implement the concept of liking / disliking an item in a `postgres` db - when the user likes / dislikes something, I want to insert an item into my DB to represent this.

This is my schema:

```
id | postID | userID | type 
 1      2        1      like
```

Now if the user has already liked the item, and now they decide to dislike it - I want to update the `type` field, from `like` to `dislike`.

Similarly, if they've disliked something and now decided to like it, I want to perform the opposite update.

Furthermore, a user can only like / dislike something once - so if the user has liked / disliked the post previously and now decides to like / dislike it again, nothing should happen.

This means I need to implement an upsert statement in `postgres`, which inserts a new row, if the user has not interacted with the post previously, and updates the `type` field, if a row with the specified `postID + userID + type` already exists.

I was looking at doing this using the `on conflict` syntax -

```
INSERT INTO table_name(postID,userID,type) 
VALUES(2,1,'like') 
ON CONFLICT (????) DO UPDATE 
  SET type = 'like'
```

but I'm not sure what to pass into the `ON CONFLICT` section, since the match needs to happen on multiple fields.

I considered setting a unique index on the (postID, userID) fields - something like this:

`create unique index idx_1 on table (postID, userID)`

The problem is I want to use this DB in the future to store comment information, and a user is allowed to comment on the same post multiple times.

An example would be:

```
id | postID | userID | type 
 1      2       1      comment
 2      2       1      comment 
 3      2       1      like
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the number of updates to a row, you can use a `check` constraint and secondary column counting the updates.

```
alter table t add column num_updates int default 1 check (num_updates <= 2);
```

Then, if you want to prevent duplicate rows on types other than `comment`, you can use a filtered unique index:

create unique index unq_table_name_postid_userid
    on table_name(postid, userid)
    where type <> 'comment';

Then I think you can express the logic using `on conflict`:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (postID, userID, type) 
    VALUES(2, 1, 'like') 
    ON CONFLICT (postID, userID) DO UPDATE 
         SET type = 'like',
             num_updates = excluded.num_updates + 1;
```

This allows only one update.  You might want more refined logic, such as updating the value only if `type` changes:

```
num_update = (excluded.num_updates = num_updates)::int + 1
```

Comment: in this solution, do I still need to add the following index to be able to use multiple fields in the on conflict clause? `create unique index on table_name (postid, userid)` if so, would this be an issue with the comment use case described in the question?

Comment: @Alk . . . Yes.  That is in your question.

Comment: Just to confirm - the above would allow me to create the example table given in my question, even though the postID and userID are the same on both of the comment rows (rows with id 1 and 2) I'm asking as I thought the unique constraint is not going to allow me to create two rows with the same userID and postID

Comment: @Alk . . . For that, you need a filtered unique index.  I'm not sure how that works with `on conflict`, alas.

Comment: You want to "use this DB in the future to store comment".  So, in the future, just create a new comments table. After all you are processing different information with different rules applied to them. Why try to shoe-horn them into the same table.